# Grpc error: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = The GRPC target is not implemented on the server,

Tags: go, grpc

I am new to grpc and trying to request google routes api through GRPC but facing an error.

< **rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = The GRPC target is not implemented on the server, host: routes.googleapis.com, method: /bkgrpc.Routes/ComputeRouteMatrixService.**>

The proto file is:

```
syntax="proto3";

package bkgrpc;

option go_package="./proto/routing";

// import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

/* services*/
service Routes{
    rpc ComputeRouteMatrixService(ComputeRouteMatrixRequest)returns (ComputeRouteMatrixResp){
        option (google.api.http)={
            post:"/routes.googleapis.com/distanceMatrix/v2:computeRouteMatrix"
            body:"*"
        };
    }
}
```

The main go file is

```
package googlerouting

import (
    routepb "bkgrpc/proto/routing"
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"
)

type Server struct {
    routepb.UnimplementedRoutesServer
}

func (*Server) ComputeRouteMatrixService(_ context.Context, in *routepb.ComputeRouteMatrixRequest) (*routepb.ComputeRouteMatrixResp, error) {
    return &routepb.ComputeRouteMatrixResp{}, nil
}

type LatLng struct {
    Latitude  float64
    Longitude float64
}

func ComputeRoute(origin []LatLng, destination LatLng, apiKey, fieldMask string) (resp *routepb.ComputeRouteMatrixResp, err error) {
    config := tls.Config{}
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("routes.googleapis.com:443", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(credentials.NewTLS(&config)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to listen", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("Connection established success!!!!")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    ctx = metadata.AppendToOutgoingContext(ctx, "X-Goog-Api-Key", apiKey)
    ctx = metadata.AppendToOutgoingContext(ctx, "X-Goog-Fieldmask", fieldMask)
    defer cancel()
    // create the origin using a latitude and longitude
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    // Attach the google compute route matrix service to the server
    routepb.RegisterRoutesServer(s, &Server{})
    client := routepb.NewRoutesClient(conn)
    // execute grpc
    origins := []*routepb.RouteMatrixOrigin{}
    for _, latLng := range origin {
        origin := &routepb.RouteMatrixOrigin{}
        waypoint := &routepb.Waypoint{
            Location: &routepb.Location{
                Latlng: &routepb.Latlng{
                    Latitude:  float32(latLng.Latitude),
                    Longitude: float32(latLng.Longitude),
                },
            },
        }
        origin.Waypoint = waypoint
        origins = append(origins, origin)
    }
    destinations := []*routepb.RouteMatrixDestinations{
        {Waypoint: &routepb.Waypoint{
            Location: &routepb.Location{
                Latlng: &routepb.Latlng{
                    Latitude:  float32(destination.Latitude),
                    Longitude: float32(destination.Longitude),
                },
            },
        }},
    }

    req := &routepb.ComputeRouteMatrixRequest{
        Origins:      origins,
        Destinations: destinations,
    }
    fmt.Println("Request: ", req)
    resp, err = client.ComputeRouteMatrixService(ctx, req)
    // resp, err = client.GoogleComputeRouteMatrix(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("GRPC error is: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Response: ", resp)
    return resp, err
}
```

Can anyone please tell what is wrong in the code.

Comment: What should `routepb.RegisterRoutesServer(s, &Server{})` achieve? Btw. it looks like Google has rather [new library](https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto) with the `"types specifically for interacting with Google APIs"`. You should try to use the `routepb` from there.

Comment: @NotX, Thank you reply. I am trying to make a custom function.